# MPAndroidChart Value formatter out of array range

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart, formatter

I wanna format XAxis values from int to String (actually date) the problem is that formatter is not stopping when ArrayList size is reached and I get out of array range exception. What can I do about this ?

```
    barEntries=new ArrayList <> (  );
    XAxisLabels=new ArrayList <> (  );
    barEntries.add ( new BarEntry ( 0,0 ) );
    XAxisLabels.add ( "2017-10-29 09:26:07" );
    barEntries.add ( new BarEntry ( 1,400 ) );
    XAxisLabels.add ( "2017-10-28 19:04:22" );
    barEntries.add ( new BarEntry ( 2,200 ) );
    XAxisLabels.add ( "2017-10-28 19:05:12" );
    barEntries.add ( new BarEntry ( 3,300 ) );
    XAxisLabels.add ( "2017-10-29 09:26:07" );

            BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet ( barEntries, "DataSet" );
            barDataSet.setColors ( ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS );

            BarData barData = new BarData ( barDataSet );

            XAxis xAxis = barChart.getXAxis ( );
            xAxis.setPosition ( XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTH_SIDED );
            xAxis.setValueFormatter ( new MyXAxisValueFormatter ( XAxisLabels ) );
            //xAxis.setGranularity ( 1 );
            xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels ( true );
            //xAxis.setAxisMinimum ( 1 );
            barChart.setData ( barData );
            barChart.notifyDataSetChanged ( );
            barChart.invalidate ( );
```

My Formatter:

```
public class MyXAxisValueFormatter implements IAxisValueFormatter{
        int counter=0;
        private ArrayList <String> mValues = new ArrayList <> (  );
        public MyXAxisValueFormatter(ArrayList<String> values)
        {
            this.mValues=values;
        }
        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue ( float value, AxisBase axis ) {
            String x;
            value=value+counter*0.3f;
            counter++;
            x= mValues.get ( (int)value);
            return x;
        }
}
```

[Application screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOVsp.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class MyXAxisValueFormatter implements IAxisValueFormatter {
private List labels;

public MyXAxisValueFormatter(List<String> labels) {
    this.labels = labels;
}

@Override
public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
    try {
        int index = (int) value;
        return labels.get(index);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "";
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It will work ... only check the conversion of float to string. This method will call automatically for each value you dont need to provide your arraylist. If it works please dont forget to mark this post as answer. Happy coding buddy :)

Comment: But how it gonna know where are Strings that it needs to take to sign x axis ?

Comment: Basically axis value formatter is called upon selected axis. So if you call it on specific axis it get values of all labels from there and convert them all one by one.

Comment: Test this you may need to change the condition of string as I dont get in your logic that what you are doing by multiplying value with 3.0f. Give it a try it will covert all of your float values to strings of given axis.Thank you :)

Comment: If you need further assistance you can text me anytime buddy :)

Comment: I uploaded screenshot to my main post so you can see it didnt change values, the question is how to convert it then ? By multiplying i was trying to fix problem that float given to method wasnt as x value added to BarEntry (method was getting 0.7 instead of 1... 1,4 instead of 2 so casting to int gave wrong index of XAxisLabels Array)

Comment: Why you want to change values to strings ?

Comment: Do you want to give something like 1.3 instead of 1300

Comment: My point is to set X axis with Dates ("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"). I am using int x values just as index related to XAxisLabels Array with Strings that I actually wanna use to my x Axis.

Comment: which version of mpAndroidCharts you are using ?

Comment: The newest one (v3.0.2). I know it would be easier with older versions, but I don't want to give up with this one.

Comment: Ok mate check updated answer, if you want to show dates on xaxis you dont need to give value formatter

Comment: show me the result after this and also let me know if you need to modify I will help you with this.

Comment: The result is the same as the screenshot I posted before.

Comment: I just edited my answer please try by applying this value formatter

Comment: Let me know if this works. Basically I used older version and this thing is very easy in older version.

Comment: Replace this ...XAxisLabels = new ArrayList <> (  ); with XAxisLabels = new ArrayList <String> (); and use value formatter as I edited in answer.

Comment: I am not able to check this at this moment but I can see that there will be probably a problem with casting float to int (I need to center bars) that I mentioned before and also index going out of range

Comment: Actually it worked :) Now I need to fix formating somehow. String are so long that one is covering next one.

Answer (score 2):

I've got **similar problem** - my formatting started at -1 - > so i had java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
So I **fixed** it like this:

```
@Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value) {

        if (((int) value) < values.size() && (int) value >= 0) {
            //Log.e(TAG, "getFormattedValue: " + (int) value); // value is -1, exception!
            String strDate = values.get((int) value);
            if (mCurrentRange == 7)
                strDate = getDayOfWeekFromStr(strDate);
            else strDate = removeYearFromDate(strDate);
            return strDate;
        } else {
            return "0";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am having some issue in adding String to xaxis

```
{
                    ArrayList<Entry> yvalues = new ArrayList<>();
                    ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
                    String[] values = new String[]{"Jan","Feb","Mac"};
                    for (int i = 0; i < graphData.getDate().size(); i++) {
                        yvalues.add(new Entry(i,Float.parseFloat(graphData.getMeasurement().get(i))));
                    }
                    lineChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
                    LineDataSet dataSet = new LineDataSet(yvalues, "Cells");
                    dataSet.setFillAlpha(110);
                    ArrayList<ILineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
                    dataSets.add(dataSet);
                    dataSet.setLineWidth(3f);
                    dataSet.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    dataSet.setColor(Color.RED);
                    LineData data = new LineData(dataSets);
                    lineChart.setData(data);
                    XAxis xAxis = lineChart.getXAxis();
                    xAxis.setValueFormatter(new MyXAxisValueFormatter(values));

                }
```

MyXAxisValueFormatter is this

```
public class XAxisValueFormatter extends IAxisValueFormatter{
    private String[] mvalues;
    public XAxisValueFormatter(String[] mvalues){
        this.mvalues = mvalues;
    }

    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
        System.out.println("value"+mvalues[(int)value]);
        return mvalues[(int)value];
    }
}
```

When adding value to `MyXAxisValueFormatter` it is showing error

> setValueFormatter(com.github.mikephil.chartinf.formatter.ValueFormatter)
>   in AxisBase cannot be applied  to
>   (com.anu.myapp.myFragment.XAxisValueFormatter)