# Labels of x axis on MPAndroid chart, not aligned with index values

Tags: mpandroidchart

I cant figure out why my labels are not aligned with my chart values in the MP Android bar chart.

there are just four bars, and each corresponds to a day (therefore Day 1, Day 2, Day 3, Day 4).

I have followed the documentation available, and looked at several similar questions, but still fail to match the labels to their values.

the code is use is as follows:

```
      View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_g_h5_fragment, container, false);

    barChart = v.findViewById(R.id.new_fragment5_chart);

    ArrayList<BarEntry> chartvals = new ArrayList<>();
    chartvals.add(new BarEntry(1, 10F));
    chartvals.add(new BarEntry(2, 20F));
    chartvals.add(new BarEntry(3, 15F));
    chartvals.add(new BarEntry(4, 18F));

    BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(chartvals, "");

    ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<>();
    labels.add("Day 1");
    labels.add("Day 2");
    labels.add("Day 3");
    labels.add("Day 4");
    //xvals.add("Day 5");

    XAxis xaxis = barChart.getXAxis();
    xaxis.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(labels));
    xaxis.setLabelCount(labels.size());
    xaxis.setGranularity(1f);

    iBarDataSets.clear();
    iBarDataSets.add(barDataSet);
    barData = new BarData(iBarDataSets);
    barChart.clear();
    barChart.setData(barData);
    barChart.invalidate();

    return v;
}
```

[see image of graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8dRM.png)

this is the image of result, where Day 1 label is missing, and labels start from Day2. also Day 4 bar does not have any corresponding label.

I have looked at several examples on stackoverflow including this one below. i remain unsuccessful

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47280607/mpandroidchart-value-formatter-out-of-array-range](https:////https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47280607/mpandroidchart-value-formatter-out-of-array-range)

Any guidance to fix this is greatly appreciated

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stackoverflow! It would be great if you could format your code a bit better, here's a guide https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting .